# How can I pass data between SelectMultipleFields?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm new to Flask and WTForms, and have been really struggling with this simple task. I want to display a list of options. The user can select multiple options, and then these choices generate a new list of selectable options.

To simplify things for now, I'm just trying to directly take the selected options from one SelectMultipleField and set those as the choices in a second SelectMultipleField:

```
class SelForm(FlaskForm):
    choices = []
    selections = SelectMultipleField('Available Streams', choices=choices)
    submit = SubmitField('Choose Streams')
```

```
@streams_blueprint.route('/select', methods=['GET','POST'])
def select():
    # Grab a selectable list of studies from database.
    form = SelForm()
    db_objects = [(stream.id, stream.name) for stream in Stream.objects()]
    form.selections.choices = db_objects
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form2 = SelForm()
        selections = form.selections.data
        form2.selections.choices = selections
    else:
        form2 = SelForm()
    return render_template('select_streams.html', form=form, form2=form2)
```

No matter what I try, the forms just always render in their initial state (`form.selections.choices=db_objects` and `form2.selections.choices=[]`). The `validate_on_submit` segment does nothing. How can I get form2 to update after I click submit?

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against this all weekend, I finally found the answer. The problem is that the default validators in `SelectMultipleField` don't actually work. If I replace `validate_on_submit` with `is_submitted`, the code runs. This version does what I want it to:

```
@streams_blueprint.route('/select', methods=['GET','POST'])
def select():
    # Grab a selectable list of studies from database.
    form = SelForm()
    db_objects = [(stream.id, stream.name) for stream in Stream.objects()]
    form.selections.choices = db_objects
    if form.is_submitted():
        form2 = SelForm()
        selections = form.selections.data
        new_objects = [(stream.id, stream.name) for stream in Stream.objects(id__in=selections)]
        form2.selections.choices = new_objects
    else:
        form2 = SelForm()
    return render_template('select_streams.html', form=form, form2=form2)
```

If I need validators, I will have to write custom ones for this field type.

[image: Works as intended]